# Clearing the screen in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have tried all the other posts on this topic but none of them have worked for me...

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

window=Tk()
window.geometry('600x400')
window.title('hello world')

def wrong():
    root=Tk()
    text=Text(root)
    text.insert(INSERT,"WRONG!, you stupid idiot!!!!")
    text.pack()
def right():
    root=Tk()
    text=Text(root)
    text.insert(INSERT,"CORRECT, good job!")
    text.pack()
def reset():
    hide_widgets()
class UIProgram():
    def setupUI(self):
        buttonlist=[]
        button= Button(window,text='Sanjam',command=wrong).pack()
        button2=Button(window,text='Sunny the Bunny',command=wrong).pack()
        button3= Button(window, text='Sunjum',command=right).pack()
        button4= Button(window, text='bob',command=wrong).pack()
        button5= Button(window, text='next',command=reset)
        button5.pack()
        self.label=Label(window)
        self.label.pack()
        window.mainloop()
program= UIProgram()
program.setupUI()
```

I am aware of pack_forget() and tried it, but it keeps giving me an error. Also, is it possible to make a command(like the 'reset' one I have) and use that in the command for a clear screen button. Please help, I am new to Tkinter and don't know much about these things..

Thanks

Comment: _"it keeps giving me an error"_. And that error is...?

Comment: @Kevin- "hide widgets is not defined"

Comment: The first thing I notice is you have 3 calls to Tk() in that program ... you should only ever have one. Are you trying to make a modal notification? Use Toplevel() for that, not Tk().

Comment: @ Novel ,I was just trying to display text, can you give me the syntax for using only one?

Comment: use `root=Toplevel()` instead `root=Tk()` inside functions If you need to display message in separated window then tkinter has `messagebox` for this.

Comment: always put full error message (Traceback) in question (as text, not screenshot). There are other useful informations.

Comment: but I still dont know how to clear the screen. Can someone answer this question plz...

Comment: it is place for comments :) Place for answers is below :)

Comment: you have many mistakes - it need some time to correct all and create example. Maybe you should find some tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Example code

I'm tired to describe the same mistakes hundreds of times - some comments in code.

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- classes ---

class UIProgram():

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master # use to add elements directly to main window

        self.buttons = [] # keep buttons to change text

        # frame to group buttons and easily remove all buttons (except `Next`)
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self. master)
        self.frame.pack()

        # group button in frame
        button = tk.Button(self.frame, text='Sanjam', command=self.wrong)
        button.pack()
        self.buttons.append(button)

        button = tk.Button(self.frame, text='Sunny the Bunny', command=self.wrong)
        button.pack()
        self.buttons.append(button)

        button = tk.Button(self.frame, text='Sunjum', command=self.right)
        button.pack()
        self.buttons.append(button)

        button = tk.Button(self.frame, text='bob', command=self.wrong)
        button.pack()
        self.buttons.append(button)

        # button outside frame
        button_next = tk.Button(self.master, text='Next >>', command=self.reset)
        button_next.pack()

        self.label = tk.Label(self.frame)
        self.label.pack()


    def wrong(self):
        # create second window with message and closing button
        win = tk.Toplevel()
        tk.Label(win, text="WRONG!, you stupid idiot!!!!").pack()
        tk.Button(win, text='close', command=win.destroy).pack()

    def right(self):
        # create second window with message and closing button
        win = tk.Toplevel()
        tk.Label(win, text="CORRECT, good job!").pack()
        tk.Button(win, text='close', command=win.destroy).pack()

    def reset(self):
        # remove frame with all buttons
        self.frame.pack_forget()
        tk.Label(self.master, text="frame removed").pack()

        # or only remove text in labels
        #for button in self.buttons:
        #    button['text'] = '-- place for new text --'

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('600x400')
root.title('hello world')

program = UIProgram(root)

root.mainloop()
```

---

BTW: if you do `var = Widget(...).pack()` then you assign `None` to `var` because `pack()/grid()/place()` return `None`. You have to do it in two lines

```
var = Widget(...)
var.pack()
```

or in one line if you don't need `var`

```
Widget(...).pack()
```